# How do I use postfix aliases in cyrus?

Tags: email, postfix, cyrus

I have a cyrus mailbox called user/nrahl. If I use the 'mail' command, from the server itself, and type:

```
mail nrahl
```

to send a message, the message magically shows up in my Thunderbird IMAP inbox. But I need to get message from a POP3 account into Cyrus for delivery, and the messages comming in are addressed to "nrahl@mydomain.com".

I have fetchmail setup and running, and it's downloading messages from the POP3 account, and passing them into Postfix. Postfix (now that I've got aliases set up in /etc/alias) is accepting the message, and passing it to the Cyrus socket.

But here's the problem: Cyrus is rejecting the message with a 550 - mailbox unknown error.

The actual message in /var/log/mail.log is:

```
Apr 17 16:56:57 IMAP cyrus/lmtpunix[5640]: verify_user(user.fetchmail) failed: Mailbox does not exist
Apr 17 16:56:57 IMAP postfix/lmtp[5561]: CFFD61556BD: to=, relay=localhost[/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp], delay=0.08, delays=0.07/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host localhost[/var/run/cyrus/socket/lmtp] said: 550-Mailbox unknown.  Either there is no mailbox associated with this 550-name or you do not have authorization to see it. 550 5.1.1 User unknown (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

It looks like it's trying to forward all of nrahl's mail to postfix@localhost, instead of nrahl@localhost, and I don't know why. I need it to forward mail addressed to nrahl@mydomain.com into Cyrus's "nrahl" mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go it!

Ok, so when your using fetchmail, you define the "alias" (local user name) in the fetchmail configuration (/etc/fetchmailrc) not in /etc/aliases. Use the smtpname directive.

Example:

```
set syslog;
set daemon 60;

poll "mail.server.com"
with protocol pop3
user "nrahl@mydomain" password "12345" is "nrahl@localhost"
fetchall
smtpname "nrahl@localhost"
```